# What is the relative path for application.properies file below?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

[image]

application.properties need to be loaded in LoadProperties.java file.

public static Properties loadProperties() {

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("application.properties");
        props.load(fis);    
        fis.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return props;
}
```

**The above code works fine in normal Java Project but when I add this in Dynamic Web project path not recognized because folder structure is differ**

I tried in many ways and got java.io.FileNotFoundException: application.properties (The system cannot find the file specified) error

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: public static Properties loadProperties() {
     
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try{
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("application.properties");
         props.load(fis);    
         fis.close();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
         ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return props;
    }

Comment: Have you tried to put a preceding slash like "/application.properties"?

Comment: Yes I tried using "/application.properties" but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

//with properties in the root dir 
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));
```

Comment: What to import to use getClass().getResourceAsStream(); because it is showing red mark there

Comment: Do we need to import any jar?

Comment: I tried props.load(LoadProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties")); but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using classloader :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("your.properties").getFile());
```

Using classloader with stream :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("your.properties");
```

Using ResourceBundle :

```
ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("your.properties", locale);
System.out.println(labels.getString("label1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I add files at eclipse installation and give path like below It works fine for me.

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("application.properties");

[image]